# Network interface disappeard from settings

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04

My network interface disappeard from the settings and I can only connect via Wifi to the internet [image: img]

How can I bring it back?

I am using Ubtuntu 22.04 LTS.

Best
Jonas

---

From the various similar questions, that in the end did not help me, here are the information that seem most relevant to tackle such problems:

```shell
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[   12.610006] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   12.623315] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   12.623340] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[   12.623801] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   13.048840] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x354
[   13.174637] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF HR B5, rfid=0x10a100
[   13.240661] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: d4:54:8b:63:3b:b6
[   13.470212] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
```

```shell
dkms status
r8168/8.049.02, 5.15.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 5.15.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```shell
sudo dmesg | grep r816
[ 2615.423220] r8168: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
```

```shell
ip -c a | sed -e 's/\// \//g'
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link /loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1 /8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1 /128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link /ether d4:54:8b:63:3b:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.68.218.197 /20 brd 10.68.223.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 1410sec preferred_lft 1410sec
    inet6 2001:638:504:d809:ceb2:dcf6:f329:2400 /64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 601766sec preferred_lft 82823sec
    inet6 2001:638:504:d809:65cc:2ea1:3f76:82ca /64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2592001sec preferred_lft 604801sec
    inet6 fe80::edad:7d8f:f9e:8266 /64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```shell
sudo lshw -c network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 20
       serial: d4:54:8b:63:3b:b6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-47-generic firmware=66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.u ip=10.68.218.197 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6053194000-6053197fff
```

---

Edit, add information from comments:

@Amirreza: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` did not help

@pilot6:

```shell
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 01)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (rev 01)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 01)
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 01)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 20)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Active Management Technology - SOL (rev 20)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0be (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5407
72:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: will `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` do any good?

Comment: Please add output of `lspci` to your question.

Comment: Please see above, I edited my question.

Comment: When you are installing Ubuntu 22.04, enable "Use proprietary drivers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing whata Amirreza suggested, I did not notice any change at first.

However, during the day I noticed that I was connected to the ethernet again. Note, that I rebooted my laptop and also (un)plugged the network cable. So I am not sure what fixed it in the end...

Anyways, thank you!